# Python: Compare two lists and update value in list2 based on value in list1

Tags: python, list

I have kinda a tricky problem I want to solve.  I have two lists:

```
word = ['run', 'windless', 'marvelous']
pron = ['rVn', 'wIndl@s', 'mArv@l@s']
```

I want to do some processing that if the value in `word` contains "less", then the corresponding value in `pron` should turn to "lIs" instead of "l@s".

Desired output:

```
pron = ['rVn', 'wIndlIs', 'mArv@l@s']
```

Any tips?  It's troublesome to me because they're in two separate lists (but same order).

Comment: "should turn to 'lIs' instead of 'l@s'" -- then it sounds like you want to fix the code that does that? (not shown)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
words = ['run', 'windless', 'marvelous']
prons = ['rVn', 'wIndl@s', 'mArv@l@s']


for (i, word) in enumerate(words):
    if "less" in word:
        prons[i] = prons[i].replace("l@s", "lIs")

print(prons)
```

Comment: One of the things I really love about well-written Python. Three people approach the same problem and write **the exact same** very readable code. (I had this solution also ready to post.)

Comment: Was about the post the exact same code too (minus the brackets).     There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like that?

```
>>> for i,w in enumerate(word):
...   if 'less' in w:
...     pron[i] = pron[i].replace('l@s','lIs')
... 
>>> pron
['rVn', 'wIndlIs', 'mArv@l@s']
```