# Python: compare two lists and update multiple values

Tags: python, string, list

This is a follow up question to: [Python: Compare two lists and update value in list2 based on value in list1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144794/python-compare-two-lists-and-update-value-in-list2-based-on-value-in-list1)

I have two lists:

```
words = ['vestments', 'absence', 'windless']
prons = ['vEstm@nts', 'abs@nts', 'wIndl@s']
```

For items in `word` matching if condition, process corresponding item in `pron`.
For example, if "less" is found in an item in `word`, change `l@s` to `lIs`.  And if `nts` is not found to be a part of a string in `word`, then replace @nts to @ns in `pron`.

I tried:

```
for (i, word) in enumerate(words):
if "less" in word:
    prons[i] = '\n'.join(prons[i])
    prons[i] = prons[i].replace("l@s", "lIs")
if "nts" not in word:
    prons[i] = prons[i].replace("@nts", "@ns")
```

Desired output:

```
pron = ['vEstm@nts', 'abs@ns', 'wIndlIs']
```

However my output is:

```
pron = ['vEstm@ns', 'abs@ns', 'wIndlIs']
```

It looks like the code is completely not reading in my "nts" if condition, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Please describe with _words_ what it is supposed to do. Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the logic here?

Comment: One problem (with what you've shown us) is that you name your lists `word` and `pron` but iterate over `words` and `prons`.

Comment: When I run this code I get different results from the ones you post here. (I get the results I would expect from the code as written.) You have mixed something up.

Comment: I ran this as well and got the results you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with two passes as follows:

```
result = [b.replace('l@s', 'lIs') if 'less' in a else b for a,b in zip(words, prons)]
result = [b.replace('@nts', '@ns') if 'nts' not in a else b for a,b in zip(words, result)]
```

---

### UPDATE

I have condensed the passes into one pass as follows:

```
result = [b.replace('l@s', 'lIs') if 'less' in a else b.replace('@nts', '@ns') if 'nts' not in a else b for a,b in zip(words, prons)]

>>> print result
['vEstm@nts', 'abs@ns', 'wIndlIs']
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: @user1899415, are you sure you are using the code exactly as I have provided above because I tested it and it works fine.